# Prevent executing next router if the request already handled

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-connect

I am using connect middleware and have multiple `router` functions like below

```
var server = connect()
  .use(connect.cookieParser("secret"))
  .use(connect.session({secret: 'keyboard cat',cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))
  .use('/somepath', connect.static(__dirname + '/somepath'))
  .use('/_someapi', function (req, res) {
      // do something
  })
  .use(function (req, res) { // default case router
      // do something
  })
  .listen(8080)
```

My problem is, even if I request for `/_someapi`, after executing its function, the next `router` gets called. I want to know that how can I prevent it? I mean if the request is already handled, then the next router should not attempt to serve it.

Returning `false` from the function and `res.end('');` doesn't help.

Comment: There has to be some other problem. If you don't call res.next(), subsequent middlewares will not be called.

Comment: I am not calling `next()`, and still it goes ahead. Could you give what possible problem must be there? I have this really simple code that I have posted, so can't figure out where and what is wrong

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. How do you know that the next middleware is called?

Comment: I tried adding `console.log()` and it shows.

Comment: The console.log show in both the /_someapi-middleware and the last one? And you're completely sure that next() is not called in the /_someapi-middleware?

Comment: Absolutely, I am sure. the control goes to both the functions one after another. and no `next` is being called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here that it is possible that those are actually different requests triggering your middleware.

In order to check this: `console.log(req.url)`.
Most annoying issue is `favicon.ico` which gives lots of headache when you don't know that browser actually is requesting it all the time.

If you are developing RESTful API or any other similar application where favicon.ico is not required, then use this middleware as one of the first.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url != '/favicon.ico') {
    return next();
  } else {
    res.status(200);
    res.header('Content-Type', 'image/x-icon');
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=4294880896');
    res.end();
  }
});
```

This will response with 200 and very long cache life so that way browser will not call it again anymore.

As well, just to clarify - are you sure you need to use `.use` instead of `.get` or any other routing solutions?